# No response from Philips HUE using ‘Philips Hue Entertainment’ (via DTLS)

Tags: networking, openssl, wireshark, philips-hue, dtls

I am trying to make working Philips Hue using ‘Philips Hue Entertainment’. I follow Philips's manual (I use OpenSSL):
https://developers.meethue.com/documentation/hue-entertainment-api#DTLS

I provided PSK key and username like described. Certificate exchange is optional.

Look at the Wireshark screenshot - DTLS handshake looks good,but I did not get any response from Philips Hue once I sent encrypted application data.

-->  [Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgAF9.png)

Any tips what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting the hue bridge from power and wait a few seconds and power back on. I've wasted countless hours with this issue. I know your problem has been solved, but maybe others will see this.

Comment: The problem was, that all HUE leds had to be turn on. Weird. But helped.

Comment: @robertLT did the bulbs have power at all or are you referring to Hue state of led was `on:false` ? I have a set of bulbs on a standard switch. If the switch gets flipped off bulbs don't have any electricity and never get the message vs needing to set `{"on":true}` via PUT to lights/lightnum/state  .